# Error installing FileSaver in Angular2

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I'm trying to use fileSaver.js https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js but I'm having troubles.

I run

```
npm install file-saver --save
npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev
```

so in package.json i have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "angular2-busy": "2.0.4",
    "angular2-modal": "2.0.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "mdn-polyfills": "2.1.1",
    "mydatepicker": "1.8.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.2",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "0.10.4",
    "primeng": "4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.2.0"
  }
```

In app.module I insert:

```
import { FileSaver } from 'angular-file-saver';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    FileSaver
  ],
...
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR in FileSaver is not a NgModule
```

Is it correctly installed? Which is correct way to import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSaver doesn't need to import in app.module. It just needs import in component:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

and use it:

```
let blob = new Blob([fileText], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "title.txt");
```